# hwclock's output is effected by DST when entering it, but not when leaving it

Tags: linux, date, busybox, timezone, dst

I set system time and RTC to the following values.

```
date -s 2021.08.30-09:59:30 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null //set system time
hwclock -w //sync RTC to system time
```

Also, /etc/TZ (which is the same file as /etc/localtime in `busybox`) is saved as

```
LMT0:00LMT-1:00,M5.5.1/10,M8.5.1/10
```

where it means that DST will be in effect at 10:00 a.m. on Monday, last week in May; and will be deactivated at 10:00 a.m. on Monday, last week in August.

I deliberately set the system time and RTC to 30 seconds earlier than the end date of DST, so as to observe system behaviour.

When DST is gone, system time (also RTC maybe?) should be substracted by one hour back.

The following is the result, and it's obvious that only system time is subtracted by one hour, NOT both system time and RTC.

```
~ # cat /etc/TZ
LMT0:00LMT-1:00,M5.5.1/10,M8.5.1/10
~ # date -s 2021.08.30-09:59:30 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
~ # hwclock -w
~ # 
~ # date
Mon Aug 30 09:59:36 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 09:59:42 2021  0.000000 seconds
~ # 
~ # 
~ # date
Mon Aug 30 09:59:49 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 09:59:53 2021  0.000000 seconds

~ # date
Mon Aug 30 09:00:00 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 10:00:03 2021  0.000000 seconds

~ # date
Mon Aug 30 09:00:05 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 10:00:06 2021  0.000000 seconds
```

However, it behaves differently on the other hand! This time I want to observe system behaviour when entering DST.

With /etc/TZ being saved as

```
LMT0:00LMT-1:00,M8.5.1/10,M12.5.1/10
```

where it means that DST will be in effect at 10:00 a.m. on Monday, last week in August; and will be deactivated at 10:00 a.m. on Monday, last week in December.

Also, I set system time and RTC to the following values.

```
date -s 2021.08.30-09:59:30 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null //set system time
hwclock -w //sync RTC to system time
```

When DST is in effect, system time (also RTC maybe?) should be added by one hour ahead.

The following is the result, and it's obvious that BOTH system time and RTC is added by one hour.

```
~ # cat /etc/TZ
LMT0:00LMT-1:00,M8.5.1/10,M12.5.1/10
~ # date -s 2021.08.30-09:59:30 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
~ # hwclock -w
~ # 
~ # date
Mon Aug 30 09:59:35 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 09:59:37 2021  0.000000 seconds
~ # date
Mon Aug 30 09:59:48 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 09:59:51 2021  0.000000 seconds
~ # date
Mon Aug 30 11:00:04 LMT 2021
~ # hwclock
Mon Aug 30 11:00:06 2021  0.000000 seconds
```

I wonder why this contradictory behavior occurs.

Comment: Did you check whether this is a known bug in busybox?

Comment: I just searched keyword hwclock on [busybox bugzilla](https://bugs.busybox.net/) and found nothing similar to this.

Comment: RTC should always be in UTC. You're using a multiuser system and those users could be from anywhere in the world.

Comment: @Bib I didn't get it. Do you mean this is a normal behaviour?

Comment: Person A is in New York, person B is in Sydney. They both must have consistency of the RTC, and that mean UTC, If you make the hw clock the time in Paris, no one will have a clue what the true time is. It is normal to have the hw clock set to UTC.

Comment: @Bib According to your thinking, the RTC should as well not be affected when entering DST. How about that?

Comment: RTC does not change for DST, that is left upto the os. It is not just my thinking, this has been the mantra ever since Unix was born. RTC does not change for DST. You seem to have a great trouble accepting this. RTC does not change for DST. RTC stays at UTC. User view of time is set by the the UTC and TZ offset. RTC does not change for DST. Please, just accept it. RTC does not change for DST.

Comment: @Bib I used to believe that the RTC would not change because of DST until I ran tests. So my goal now is to find out who changes the RTC when entering DST?

Comment: RTC does not change for DST. Dual boot system with Windows?  RTC does not change for DST. It's your own action? RTC does not change for DST. Perhaps you have misunderstood. RTC does not change for DST.

Comment: @Bib The environment is single image with linux-3.10 version. According to my test, which is in OP, RTC is changed by someone RIGHT AWAY when entering DST. I searched the whole source files and found nobody doing this action. I'm now suspecting operating system doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking that `hwclock` displays the exact value the hardware clock has in its registers.

**It does not do that.**

Proof:

```
# date; hwclock; TZ=UTC hwclock; grep rtc_time /proc/driver/rtc
Wed  1 Sep 18:33:18 EEST 2021
2021-09-01 18:33:18.870798+03:00
2021-09-01 15:33:18.981738+00:00
rtc_time        : 15:33:20
```

Note how the outputs of `hwclock` and `TZ=UTC hwclock` are different?

`hwclock` displays the value of the hardware clock *converted to current timezone as necessary (including both the DST offset and the timezone)*. If you want to see the raw value, you must use `cat /proc/driver/rtc`: depending on whether your system uses classic PC CMOS clock driver, UEFI clock interface, or some other real-time-clock driver, there might or might not be a conversion to `time_t` (or `time64_t`) and back in the clock setting process too.

You also don't use the `--utc` nor `--local` options when getting/setting the hardware clock, so the local/UTC state of the hardware clock is determined by the third line of the `/etc/adjtime` file, if it exists.

---

In your first test, you are setting the hardware clock while DST is in effect, and so the UTC offset is -1 (UTC=local - 1 hour). If the HW clock is set to use local time, it will be set to 09:59:30 as expected.

But if the HW clock is set to use UTC, the actual value set to the clock registers will be **08**:59:30. When you view the clock before the DST transition, this offset is automatically taken back out by `hwclock`, and so you will see 09:59:** as expected.

When the transition off DST happens, if the HW clock was set to local time, the clock register will increment to the value of 10:00:00. Since it's already local time and DST offset is now 0 anyway, `hwclock` will display it as 10:00:00.

But if the HW clock was set to UTC time, the value in the clock registers would now be 09:00:00. Since after the DST transition the UTC offset is now 0, `hwclock` would also display it as 09:00:00.

The OS clock always runs internally in UTC and converts to local time according to the timezone+DST rules, so it will display 09:00:00 (non-DST) as expected.

Since you got the `hwclock` result of 10:00:00 here, it appears the third line of your `/etc/adjtime` file must say `LOCAL`.

---

In your second test, you set the clock while DST is not in effect, and so the total UTC offset is 0. Now, the clock registers will be set to 09:59:30 regardless of whether it's set to use UTC or local time. From the previous test, we know you have it set to local time.

When the DST transition time arrives, the HW clock registers will read 10:00:00... and as the register value is formatted for display according to the current timezone, there is a problem: according to the timezone rules in effect, **10:00:00 local time does not exist today!**

Because of the DST transition, there is no possible UTC timestamp value that could represent the value of 10:00:00 local time on this special day: 09:59:59 UTC is 09:59:59 local time, but 10:00:00 UTC is 11:00:00 local time. As the time value goes through `glibc`'s timezone translation and formatting routines, the non-existent 10:00:00 gets pushed to 11:00:00.

And so, if you query the hardware clock during the first hour after the DST-to-standard-time transition, **`hwclock` may tell you an incorrect time** because the actual value in the clock registers cannot be represented as a valid local time value. This is just a display artifact: `/proc/driver/rtc` should still show the correct value even during this magic hour.

---

This was a great example of the kinds of surprise headaches that can be caused by having the hardware clock set to local time.

I'll end with a link to [this very applicable 10-minute YouTube video by Tom Scott on computer timekeeping.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) I'm sure you'll appreciate the conclusion.